# Compact Operators: Separable Range

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Given Banach spaces $E$ and $F$.

Consider a bounded operator:
$$T:E\to F:\quad\|T\|<\infty$$

Certainly one has:
$$T\text{ compact}\implies\mathcal{R}T\text{ separable}$$
What about the converse?

Comment: It's true that compact implies separable range. The other direction I suspect does not hold. Why not try to find a counterexample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's true that compact implies separable range. You can find a proof of this in Abramovich/Aliprantis' Problems in Operator Theory.

The other direction does not hold. To see this consider the identity operator on $\ell^2$. Since $\ell^2$ is separable the range of the identity is (since it equals the whole space). But the unit ball is compact if and only if the space is finite dimensional hence the identity operator is not compact.

Comment: Can u explain me what compact operators makes special apart from having separable range? I would like to understand the idea behind this definition.

Comment: On a Hilbert space compact operators are limits of finite rank operators. For further information about where they turn up, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator.

Comment: Yes sure but I would like to understand what makes them *sooo* special - I mean there must be some reasoning for considering them as an extra class of operators themselves (somethink like "bounded operators are precisely the continuous one").

Comment: @Freeze_S Compact operators have much nicer properties than arbitrary operators. You can think of them as behaving a bit like operators on finite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: @MattN.: Yeah I know this imagination (thats why I thought separability could be the crucial point) but there must be a solid reasoning why compact operators

Comment: @MattN.: I opened a new thread on this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816352/what-makes-compact-operators-special